# Service or Factory, and how to get there with $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What are the accepted methods of getting $http requests into services and factories? The only method I've found so far feels like there is too much code in the controller. I feel the service and/or factory should do all the heavy lifting and the data should be returned from there, but as the following code shows, I'm doing a success call inside the controller.

I don't feel like this is the correct way to do things, but it's the only way I've found to work so far.

(inside my service object)

```
this.monsterList = $http.get('data/monsters.json');
```

(inside my controller)

```
monsterService.monsterList.success(function(data) { fight.monsterList = data });
```

Is there a way to get the full success call inside the service (or maybe a factory) so that I could simply call this in the controller?

```
monsterService.monsterList
```

or

```
monsterService.getMonsterList()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this and we can argue about which ones are better, but for services I generally do something like:

```
return {
    monsterList: [],
    fetchMonsters: function () {
        return $http.get("data/monsters.json").success(function (data) {
            this.monsters = data.monsters;
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Then in the controller you can do

```
monsterService.fetchMonsters();
// data bind monsterService.monsterList
```

Since you `return $http` you can also chain a `.success` (or `.error`) callback in the controller if you have to.

Comment: Yeah, angular haves many ways for doing the same thing and yours is new for me. Nice code, I like it.

Comment: If you use $resource instead you don't even need the success handler at all.

Comment: I tried this method but I only got back the promise object, not the data. I set it up slightly differently, using a service instead of returning an object so this.getMonsterList = function () { (etc.) } and then ran monsterService.getMonsterList()

I'm trying to get out of having to chain the success in the controller if possible.

Comment: @Organiccat depending upon what you do you shouldn't necessarily have to use the promise in the controller or manipulate the data directly (so you shouldn't have to return it).  Instead you can do something like `this.monsters = monsterService.monsterList`.  Then in the view you could use `controllerAs.monsters` and it would update when `$http` is complete automatically because of the data bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You could absolutely build a function named `getMonsterList` and then leverage that in an `ng-repeat`. For example, it might look something like this:

```
... ng-repeat="item in monsterService.getMonsterList()"
```

and then the method itself:

```
function getMonsterList() {
    if ($scope.items === undefined) {
        $scope.items = [];
    }

    // here you write the code to asynchronously get the items
    // the success callback would then update the items array

    return $scope.items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to define a service with an object and then inject it in the controller

For example (I am using Coffeescript, I can provide you with JS code if you want) the service:

```
pitagoras.factory 'Comment', ($resource) ->
  class Occurrence
    constructor: ->
      @service = $resource '/comments', {}, {
        'all': {method: 'GET'},
        'create': {method: 'POST'}
      }
    all: () ->
      @service.all()
    create: (data) ->
      @service.create(data)
  new Occurrence()
```

Then on my controller I just inject the service and call it like this:

```
comment.controller 'CommentController', ($scope, Comment $stateParams) ->
  Comment.query {id: activityId}, (data) ->
    $scope.comments = data
```